# combination of letters with three and more letters

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, random, cpu-word

I want to remove the single string and want to keep string with minimum length 3 and above i tried to access string with this if(result.string >= 3) but it is giving array length so i tried to access string but i cant. so please anybody who can help me

```
let stringCombinations = (str) => {
    let strLength = str.length;
    let result = [];
    let currentIndex = 0;
    while (currentIndex < strLength) {
      let char = str.charAt(currentIndex);
      let x;
      let arrTemp = [char];
      for (x in result) {
        arrTemp.push("" + result[x] + char);
    }
      result = result.concat(arrTemp);
      currentIndex++;
    }
    return result;
  };
  console.log(stringCombinations("BLADE"));

This is my ouput
output: (31) ["B", "L", "BL", "A", "BA", "LA", "BLA", "D", "BD", "LD", "BLD", "AD", "BAD", "LAD", "BLAD", "E", "BE", "LE", "BLE", "AE", "BAE", "LAE", "BLAE", "DE", "BDE", "LDE", "BLDE", "ADE", "BADE", "LADE", "BLADE"]


This is what I want
["BLA", "BLD", "BAD", "LAD", "BLAD", "BLE", "BAE", "LAE", "BLAE", "BDE", "LDE", "BLDE", "ADE", "BADE", "LADE", "BLADE"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in [@shabs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3186088/shabs) answer, you can filter your output array to match your needs.

However, here is a function that will find only the combinations matching a minimum length :

```
function stringCombinations(str, length) {
    let results;

    if (length == 1)
        results = str.split(""); // Append every character
    else
        results = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        let startChar = str.charAt(i);

        let remainingStr = str.substring(i + 1);
        let subCombinations = stringCombinations(remainingStr, Math.max(1, length - 1));

        subCombinations.forEach(combination => {
            results.push(startChar + combination);
        })
    }

    return results;
}
```

For `"ABC", 2` as input, it will give you `["AB", "AC", "ABC", "BC"]`

Answer (score 0):

You want to [filter your array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) using the [string length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length):

```js
["B", "L", "BL", "A", "BA", "LA", "BLA", "D", "BD", "LD", "BLD", "AD", "BAD", "LAD", "BLAD", "E", "BE", "LE", "BLE", "AE", "BAE", "LAE", "BLAE", "DE", "BDE", "LDE", "BLDE", "ADE", "BADE", "LADE", "BLADE"]
  .filter(s => s.length >= 3)
  .forEach(s => console.log(s))
```